# Definition of [reachability] confuses the graph-theoretic concept with the iOS app/API. Create [ios-reachability] and retag?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6182719/revisions) for [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) does not define the [concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability), it reads like a commercial for the iOS app/API:

> *Reachability is an iOS sample application which demonstrates how to use the SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an iPhone or iPod touch. In particular, it demonstrates how to know when IP can be routed and when traffic will be routed through a Wireless Wide Area Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.*

The term ['reachability' in graph-theory has been around since 1950s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reachability&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creachability%3B%2Cc0), whereas Apple only launched their API recently, then separately came up with yet another use of the name for iPhone 6/6 Plus large-screen panning (https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-reachability-on-iphone-6-6-plus/) [[2]](https://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/iphone/what-is-reachability/QYKAPUFPA9XUAXUH2).

Questions on (iOS) Reachability tend to be about API programming issues and errors, not algorithms, so they're merely an artifact of Apple's choice of name.

There is also a separate concept of URL reachability, which is distinct to both uses. How to handle it?

- **Proposal:**

  - create [ios-reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-reachability) for the app
  - redefine [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) to refer to [the graph concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability). Add a note *DO NOT USE THIS TAG for ios Reachability app/API , use [ios-reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-reachability)*
  - retag accordingly. Note [~95% of existing questions refer to the iOS app, not the concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability). But moving them seems like the right thing in this case, since the tag was misleadingly named generically in the first place.
- what do do about *URL reachability*? I don't think we have enough usage to justify [url-reachability], but should such questions should be untagged [reachability]?
- Was the approval of the previous tag wiki normal everyday behavior on SO, how do we also tell [the users who approved that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/500540) to take a little more care?

Data (some overlaps):

- [824 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) tagged [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability)
- [593 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability+ios) tagged [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- [141 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reachability+AND+graph-traversal+is%3Aq) mentioning reachability + graph-traversal
- [135 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability+swift) tagged [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)
- [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breachability%5D+url+is%3Aq)[reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) url
- [11 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breachability%5D+android+is%3Aq) [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) android
- [10 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breachability%5D+graph+is%3Aq) [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) graph
- [7 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breachability%5D+tree+is%3Aq) [reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reachability) tree
- Misc: [48 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breachability%5D+-ios+-swift+-apple+-iphone+-watchos2+-ip+-internet+-wifi+-wi-fi+-host-app+-AFNetworking+-UIApplication+-UIViewController+-Xcode+-url+-3g+-fsck+is%3Aq)

  - includes neo4j and [git reflog expire and git fsck --unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184344/git-reflog-expire-and-git-fsck-unreachable)

Comment: As ever, a downvote without comment doesn't tell us anything constructive: did you oppose changing the tag? or just the choice of name? what's your alternative suggestion?